# Upgrade Electron in Electron Forge application

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I have an Electron Forge application. I've hit a bug in Electron which is marked as resolved in v4.0.1, so I need to upgrade my application to use at least Electron 4.0.1

It seems though, that Electron Forge depends on a package named [electron-prebuilt-compile](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt-compile), which only goes up to 4.0.0, limiting how far it is possible to upgrade.

Is there any way to upgrade an Electron Forge application past Electron 4.0.0?

Comment: There are several attempts to upgrade electron version among the PRs. ([for example](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt-compile/pull/81)) Aren't they working?

Comment: @pergy Thanks for mentioning that, I did try that but I was unable to create a working build of electron-prebuilt-compile. I'd accept instructions on how to get that working as an answer. (For the time being, I've switched to electron forge v6 which avoids the problem entirely. This is still in beta though, so I'm leaving the question open hoping for an answer that works with the stable version of forge).